# Why Column auto scroll to the bottom if banner scrolls during a period time in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Here is my Code:

```
private fun HomeContent(homepageBean: HomePageBean) {
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                .padding(
                    0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 80.dp
                )

        ) {

            if (homepageBean.bannerList != null && homepageBean.bannerList.isNotEmpty()) {
                Banner(
                    pagerModifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
                    data = homepageBean.bannerList, onImagePath = {
                        homepageBean.bannerList[it].bannerUrl
                    }, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                    pagerIndicatorModifier = Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = 5.dp, end = 12.dp),
                    loopPeriod = 4000,
                    imageCorner = 12.dp
                ) {
                    homepageBean.bannerList[it].run {
                        handleItemClick(
                            requireContext(),
                            redirectType,
                            redirectUrl,
                            appletRedirectUrl
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            if (homepageBean.coreAreaListOne != null && homepageBean.coreAreaListOne.isNotEmpty()) {
                CoreArea(homepageBean.isBound, homepageBean.coreAreaListOne, true)
            }
            if (homepageBean.coreAreaListTwo != null && homepageBean.coreAreaListTwo.isNotEmpty()) {
                CoreArea(homepageBean.isBound, homepageBean.coreAreaListTwo, false)
            }
            if (homepageBean.announcementList != null && homepageBean.announcementList.isNotEmpty()) {
                CommunityMessage(homepageBean.announcementList)
            }


            if (homepageBean.resHotAreaDTOList != null) {
                PopularArea(homepageBean.resHotAreaDTOList)
            }

            if (homepageBean.publicBenefitPageVOList != null && homepageBean.publicBenefitPageVOList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                Charity(homepageBean.publicBenefitPageVOList)
            }

            HelpItem()
    ...

        }
    }
```

After scroll to the bottom, when banner scroll after a peroid time , the screen will auto scroll to the top ,maybe  60px? why? ,it seems that rememberScrollState not woring when scroll to the bottom with banner scrolls ,Could somebody tell me why this happens

if banner scrolls , I want to keep the scroll status of the whole column